# C# mysql parameterized query

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this peace of code where I need to retrieve data from `Mysql`. If I use parameterized query it does not take actual parameter value instead it takes parameter name as value.

> Error: @choise must be defined

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("");
MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;
DataSet DS;
private string columnValue = xxx;
private string Choise = yyy;
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE " + columnValue + " = @choise";
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@choise", Choise));
DS = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
connection.Close();
```

when I run this i get query like:

`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE xxx = @choise`

instead of

`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE xxx = yyy`.
Where is the problem?

I have tried:
`command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@choise", Choise));`
`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@choise", Choise);`

It works fine when I'm using actual variables instead of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run `Prepare()` on the command before adding parameters:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from table2 where " + columnValue + " = @choise";
command.Prepare();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@choise", Choise);
```

Comment: when i get Fatal error exception it says that "Parameter @choise must be defined" where it is obvious that it is defined already....

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `" + columnValue + "` = @choise";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@choise", Choise);
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was posting two lines of code, but for some reason the first one went missing. I've just edited my answer. You just need to remove the single quotes surrounding the parameter in your command. Parameters are smart about their types so they don't need the quotes (same applies to date parameters). So firs line goes like this: command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `" + columnValue + "` = @choise";

Comment: it does not execute `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@choise", Choise);`  or if it does it can't take value for some reason....

Comment: use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("choise", Choise);` instead

Comment: i did remove my statement looks like you wrote, but problems still exists.... "`@choise is not defined`"

Comment: still it puts parameter name inside statement rather than value of it

Comment: @Menelaos Vergis same error did not helped removing @

Comment: That's bizarre. Perhaps it is not taking the parameter correctly as varchar. What is the type of the xxx field? Is it not varchar or something alike? How about you try to set the parameter type explicitly like: command.Parameters.Add("@choise", SqlDbType.String); Then set the value using: command.Parameters["@choise"].Value = Choise; //I'm going from my memory, so make sure you use SqlDbType.String is correct for MySql.

Comment: Another thing to check is the value of Choise = yyy. What is yyy? Is it string? Does it have single quotes? After you removed the single quotes like I told you, your code is now correct, so there must be something wrong with the value of Choise that is posting it as a parameter @choise instead of its value. Only single quotes can do that as far as I know. Please check and let me know.